# I just rented a Kimisufi server, and I run a smartctl, is my hdd going to fail soon?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I just rented a kimisufi server and I wanted to check if the HDD was going to fail soon.... I run a smartcl --all  and this are the result

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
1   Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
2   Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
3   Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   100   100   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       390
4   Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
5   Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
7   Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
8   Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
9   Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
10  Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
12  Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   206   206   000    Old_age   Always       -       29 (Min/Max 16/32)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

I'm scared of all the Pre-fail..... can someone help me reading it correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Pre-fail` and `Old_age` types show that if the values are exceeded, it's an impending failure, or just an effect of old age. It doesn't mean you're due a failure, just how to interpret that particular row *should* this row be beyond the threshold.

The column you should keep an eye on is the `WHEN_FAILED`, for a value of `FAILING_NOW`.

More information can be found [here](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Howto_ReadSmartctlReports_ATA#When_Failed)

> Attributes Type
>
> Note that if an Attribute is of type 'Pre-fail', it does not mean that
>   your disk is about to fail! It only has this meaning if the
>   Attribute's current Normalized value is less than or equal to the
>   threshold value.
>
> Column "When Failed"
>
> If the Attribute's current "Normalized value" is less than or equal to
>   the threshold value, then the attribute is marked with "FAILING_NOW"
>   in column WHEN_FAILED.

Comment: Ok but how reliable this hdd?? I was moving from my old server to this one... but I'm starting to get scared and lose the data on it :/

Comment: @Aliceiw What is worrying you? There are no issues in your output.

Comment: ok so basically I should keep an eye on the WHEN_FAILED column

Comment: @Aliceiw Yes, indeed. Currently the hard drive looks pretty much brand new.

Comment: Its a brand new disk, only online for approx 3hrs. Its fine. Dont trust SMART, backup! 3 is 2, 2 is 1, 1 is none.

Comment: @Aliceiw - We cannot predict what will happen.  You should keep backups to the level, that makes you feel comfortable, or request the company replace the drive.